# Is there another way to open "Developer Center" in Sitecore. Currently it is not open in my browser (check with all)

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

Is there another way to open "Developer Center" in Sitecore. Currently it is not open in my browser (check with all) & i open with desktop option. In Internet Explorer its Sitecore option is visible in below left corner but when click to it doesn't open.

So any body have have an idea how can I open Developer Center this is because i want to create new Sublayout.

I haven't got any answers, please takes an attention & give me an idea over this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I highly recommend NOT using Developer Center.  To create a sublayout, it's much easier to use the content editor and Visual Studio.  Here's the steps I use:

1. Copy an existing sublayout ASCX in my solution and rename to my new sublayout name.
2. Clean up namespaces and class names as needed.
3. In Content Editor, navigate to **\sitecore\Layout\Sublayouts**
4. Insert a new sublayout definition
5. In the Ascx File field on the sublayout, specify the path to my sublayout ASCX that I just created
6. In the Placeholder field on the sublayout, specify the placeholder.

If you have to use Developer Center, then you are correct to be trying to access it via the Desktop using the **sitecore > Development Tools > Developer Center** menu item.  If the dialog does not open, do you get an error?

With Internet Explorer, you may want to ensure you are in compatibility mode if you are using IE9 or greater.  Also try opening it in another browser like Firefox or Chrome to see if it's a configuration issue or a browser issue.

Comment: Thanks, Your first option is my answer. Thanks a lot.                  For Second >> I am using IE8 & when i click on Sitecore it doesn't response & there is no error. But when i open in another system it visible. I dnt know why it is not open in my system. But your first option also do same work for me. Thanks !!  ::)